# Applying excel formula for an entire column

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with Time(e.g `4:00:07`) and an integer (`25`). I have inserted an additional column between the two.I want to extract the minute information from the Time column and apply it to the newly inserted column.

I am using the excel formula `=TEXT(A:A,"hh:mm")` which works fine for a single cell/column, but I am not able apply it for the entire column. How do I do this?

Comment: Change your formula, which I'm guessing is in cell B1, to be: `=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm")` and then copy it down.

Comment: If you insist on having something defined on the whole column you *could* also select the whole column `B` and then enter your formula `=TEXT(A:A,"hh:mm")` into the first cell of the selected area. Then you confirm the input by pressing `<cntrl><shift><return>`. This will apply the formula as a **matrix formula** onto the whole column.